# How to submit hadoop MR job remotely on Amazon EMR cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr

Current situation: I have an EMR cluster. On the master node - I have a python program that does a subprocess call and executes the script that contains the following line. The subprocess triggers the MR job and writes output to HDFS that I use later.

```
/usr/bin/hadoop jar test.jar testing.jobs.TestFeatureJob /in/f1.txt /in/f2.txt
```

What do I want to do?
Now, I want to decouple this part. I want to run the python program locally on my laptop or a separate EC2 instance but still submit the MR job to the EMR cluster. Let's say I have the test.jar on the EMR Master node.

How do I submit this remotely? Also, I am using Python and let's also assume the JAR to be a black box. Is there any package that I can use to submit the jobs? Do I have to mention like an IP of Master node to be able to run this?

Comment: How about create a web app that accepts job input requests?

Comment: @cricket_007 - can you please elaborate on this a little? Where is this web app going to run? Correct me if I am wrong - but you are suggesting is to create a long-running process that runs on the master node and accepts requests to run Hadoop jobs?

Comment: Essentially, yes. You can use EC2, EKS, AWS Lambda... Anything that can accept requests and execute Hadoop commands. Airflow or Oozie would be options that exist in the Hadoop landscape for scheduling jobs

Answer (score 0):

Basically once the Hadoop conf is set on the remote machine you can run Hadoop or spark remotely.

I attach here a link of spark-submit remote documentation of AWS but it's the same for MR. I mean once you finish this steps Hadoop jar suppose to work.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-submit-spark-job-remote-cluster/